# Jquery window scroll. call just one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, call, window-scroll

Hi I have one question about jquery window scroll function. I have code somthing like this.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".pages").offset().top) {
            $('.top-slider').slick('slickPause');
        }else {
            $('.top-slider').slick('slickPlay');
        }
    });
```

Ok every time when you scroll if first is true it call every 1px scrolled window. Is that way to call just one time if true but check on scroll if other is true call that just one time?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with a flag, something like this:

```
var paused = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $(".pages").offset().top ) {
        if( !paused ){
            $('.top-slider').slick('slickPause');
            paused = true;
        }        
    }else {
        if( paused ){
            $('.top-slider').slick('slickPlay');
            paused = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a test variable will be a solution here :

```
var checkDown = true; 
var checkUp   = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".pages").offset().top && checkDown ) {
        $('.top-slider').slick('slickPause');
        checkDown = false;
        checkUp   = true;
    }else if(checkUp) {
        $('.top-slider').slick('slickPlay');
        checkDown = true;
        checkUp   = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: two boolean for two states ?

Answer (score 1):

I tell you another solution, is a debouncer. Debounce functions make scroll and resize events more efficient, because stop the event firing till the end of the first fired event.

You can view a debounce function with underscore.js library.

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

The use is simple:

```
var debounced = _.debounce(myFunction, 1000);
$(window).scroll(debounced);
```

Comment: it's cool but I don't want to include big library for one easy way. but thanks it's cool library

Comment: It's an example, you can copy only the code of the debouncer. You can see it here: http://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce and with this you don't need to include a library. Note: underscore is not a big library. It is very tiny.